# NetfilterQueue set_payload not work

Tags: python, iptables, packet, netfilter

I am using `NetfilterQueue` and scapy to finish a monitor and tamper packet program.

But I just get into trouble that the `NetfilterQueue` module's `set_payload()` method seemed not work for me.

Here is my source code.

```
from netfilterqueue import NetfilterQueue as nfqueue
from scapy.all import *
import os
import socket
import re

baidu_ip = socket.gethostbyname('www.baidu.com')
print "Got baidu ip: " + baidu_ip

iptablesr = 'iptables -t mangle -A POSTROUTING -p tcp -j NFQUEUE --queue-num 1'
print("Adding iptable rules :")
print(iptablesr)
os.system(iptablesr)
iptablesr = 'iptables -t mangle -A POSTROUTING -p udp -j NFQUEUE --queue-num 1'
print(iptablesr)
os.system(iptablesr)


def callback(packet):
    modified = False
    sca_pkt = IP(packet.get_payload())

    # This is the main logic, to modify the packet
    try:
        dns_lookup = re.search(r'DNS Qry "([\w\.]+)"', sca_pkt[DNS].summary()).group(1)
        if re.search(r'baidu\.com', dns_lookup) != None:
            sca_pkt[DNS].qd = DNSQR(qname='www.163.com')
            sca_pkt[UDP].len = len(bytes(sca_pkt[UDP]))
            sca_pkt[UDP].chksum = 0x0000
            modified = True
    except:
        pass

    # Accept the modified packet
    if modified == True:
        print 'debug sca_pkt: ' + sca_pkt.summary()
        packet.set_payload(str(sca_pkt))
        print 'debug packet: ' + IP(packet.get_payload()).summary()
        packet.accept()
        return 

    packet.accept()

def main():
    q = nfqueue()
    q.bind(1, callback)
    try:
        q.run()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        q.unbind()
        print "Flushing iptables."
        os.system('iptables -F')
        os.system('iptables -F -t mangle')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

And this is the output I got.

```
Got baidu ip: 180.97.33.108
Adding iptable rules :
iptables -t mangle -A POSTROUTING -p tcp -j NFQUEUE --queue-num 1
iptables -t mangle -A POSTROUTING -p udp -j NFQUEUE --queue-num 1
debug sca_pkt: IP / UDP / DNS Qry "www.163.com" 
debug packet: IP / UDP / DNS Qry "baidu.com."
```

You can see from the debug info, the `set_payload()` didn't work. (I set the packet to be the value shown in `sca_pkt`, but when I then get the packet payload summary, it's still the original value)

And I just tried two version of `NetfilterQueue` including the pip version and https://github.com/kti/python-netfilterqueue.git version.

So could anybody help me? I am just very curious about this.

Comment: Did you find a fix for this? stuck with same problem

Answer (score 0):

I don't know which scapy version you are using, but `set_payload` is useally deprecated.

Insead of:

```
packet.set_payload(str(sca_pkt))
```

You should try something like:

```
packet.payload = sca_pkt.payload
```

Be aware that this will also change the UDP field. If you only wanted the DNS to change, you would use:

```
packet[DNS] = sca_pkt[DNS]
```

Comment: I know that set_payload is usually deprecated, but the version I am using is not. At least, the document didn't say that. Ant these two ways is not correct. The program will raise TypeError exception, because the netfilterqueue.Packet object does not support item assignment or the attribute payload is not wirteable.

Comment: Have you tried updating your scapy version ? (Download the DEV one on GitHub)

Comment: No, I will try later. Thanks a lot!

Comment: I don't thins this is Scapy's issue. set_payload() is a netfilterqueue's method rather than Scapy's method!

Answer (score 0):

instead of :

```
packet.set_payload(str(sca_pkt))
```

try:

```
packet.set_payload(b'sca_pkt')
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, it seems it is due to the fact that netfilterqueue is kind of deprecated, a simple fix would be to instead of setting the payload and accepting the packet, drop the packet and send directly the altered packet with scapy

```
if modified == True:
    print 'debug sca_pkt: ' + sca_pkt.summary()
    print 'debug packet: ' + IP(packet.get_payload()).summary()
    packet.drop()
    send(sca_pkt)
```